# Is it possible to use elasticsearch to generate tracking funnels?

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, analytics

We're using Mixpanel and are really happy with the ability to create funnels after-the-fact.  We're starting to use elasticsearch and are considering replicating some of our tracking to it but it's not clear if we can use it to generate funnels.

Is this possible with elasticsearch?  If so, how would I set up the aggregations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a tool with elasticsearch for funnel visualization using real log data, check the following link

https://github.com/yuecen/elastic_funnel

You can query your elasticsearch using a simple command, which looks like:

```
elastic_funnel --stages landingpage login searchpage --start 2016-03-25T00:00:00
```

docker support,

```
docker run -it --rm -v ~/.elastic_funnel:/root/.elastic_funnel:ro yuecen/elastic_funnel elastic_funnel --stages landingpage login searchpage
```

A funnel visualization with ASCII characters will been returned

```
Funnel: landingpage --> login --> searchpage 
######################################################################## 
██████████████████████████████████████████████████  27  100.0%  landingpage          
██████████████                                       8  29.6%   login        
█                                                    1  12.5%   searchpage
```

Comment: Very interesting.. going to check it out!

Comment: The percentage points trend from a stage to its next as Mixpanel display.